# How do you overwrite data instead of appendRow?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently the code below appends new data to my spreadsheet every time it runs and I have to manually remove the data before running.

```
{ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("blank");
  var sheetName = ss.getSheetByName("Team Database");
  var url = "blank";
  var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url));
  var current = 1;
  if(response.returnData && response.returnData.equipos.length > 0) 
  {
    for(var team in response.returnData.equipos) 
    {
      if(response.returnData.equipos[team].members.length > 0) 
      {
        var i = 0;
        while(i < response.returnData.equipos[team].members.length)
        {
          console.log(response.returnData.equipos[team].name);
          console.log(response.returnData.equipos[team].members[i].userId);
          sheetName.appendRow([response.returnData.equipos[team].name, response.returnData.equipos[team].members[i].userId]);
          i++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if(team.length > 0) 
  {
    sheetName.getRange('D2').setValue('=NOW()');
    sheetName.getRange('D1').setValue(sheetName.getRange('D2').getValue());
    sheetName.getRange('D2').clear();
  }
}
```

Is there a function that would overwrite it instead like: `sheetName.overwriteRow([response.returnData.equipos[team].name, response.returnData.equipos[team].members[i].userId]);`?

Comment: Just set value and replace the row value?

Comment: Which row(s) do you want to overwrite?

Comment: I want to return all values to colunm A and B
The current output is
Team:PlayerID
and continues until it loops through all players and all teams.

Comment: I mean, if you don't want to append new rows but overwrite existing ones, what criteria should be used to decide which rows get overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunc() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("blank");
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Team Database");
  var url = "blank";
  var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url));
  var current = 1;
  let oA = [];
  if (response.returnData && response.returnData.equipos.length > 0) {
    for (var team in response.returnData.equipos) {
      if (response.returnData.equipos[team].members.length > 0) {
        var i = 0;
        while (i < response.returnData.equipos[team].members.length) {
          console.log(response.returnData.equipos[team].name);
          console.log(response.returnData.equipos[team].members[i].userId);
          oA.push([response.returnData.equipos[team].name, response.returnData.equipos[team].members[i].userId]);
          i++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (team.length > 0) {
    sh.getRange('D2').setValue('=NOW()');
    sh.getRange('D1').setValue(sh.getRange('D2').getValue());
    sh.getRange('D2').clear();
    sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow() - 2, sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
    sh.getRange(3,1,oA.length, oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
  }
}
```